# To bring up a spring-cloud-config-server component with multiple git url

Tags: java, yaml, spring-cloud-config

How to map a URI to another URI in the `application.yml` of a spring-cloud-config server ?

I'm trying to deploy my spring-cloud-config-server application using Jenkins. I've defined the Git URL as `<gitRepo>/{profile}-application.properties`. Because I'm deploying the application without sending the profile, it is taking default as the profile and application is trying to reach `<gitRepo>/default-application.properties` which doesn't exist and therefore the health check on the application is failing as a part of the jenkins pipeline.

I now want to map URI : `<gitRepo>/default-application.properties` to URI : `<gitRepo>/cit-application.properties`.

Can this be done in the YML? I found many ways to only have multiple URIs based on the repositories, but that is not what I'm looking for.

```
    spring:
      cloud:
        config:
          server:
            git:
              uri: https://<gitrepo>/{profile}-configuration.git

                pattern:
                    - '*/default-configuration'
                uri: https://<gitrepo>/cit-configuration.git
```

Comment: I recommend adding relevant configuration file contents in separate code-blocks. This could be some possibly relevant contents of the Jenkins-configuration. What I would like to know is what do you mean by "mapping" the URIs? There are many ways to map URIs back and forth, but I feel like you are trying to find a workaround for something.

Comment: Hi Igor, Thanks for your response. I meant adding a rule in yml to mapp the 
uri: https://<repo>/default-configuration.git
          paths:
            pattern:
              - '*/default*'
            uri: https://repo/cit-configuration.git

The idea is to match the pattern in the path of the incoming URI and map it to the uri underneath. This doesn't seem to be working is there anything else that can be done ?

Answer (score 1):

we've disabled the health check by using 
healthcheck:
   enabled: false

That helped us resolve the issue.